# how to have a menu across top with links left aligned and right aligned

Tags: html, css

this may seem simple. I have a menu across the top of the page currently right aligned.
I want one link to be to the left of the page. How do it?

```
 <div id="toptop"> 
     <ul id="bottomnavlistl">
    <li class="a">
             <a href="@Url.Content("~/Account/EditDetails/")">LOGIN</a>
             <a href="@Url.Content("~/Account/LogOff/")">LOGOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li class="first"><a href="@Url.Content("~")">HOME</a></li>
```

css

```
    ul#bottomnavlistl li
{    
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #8A8575; 
    float:right;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css should have somthing like

```
.a{float:left;}
.first{float:right}
```

A [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mikaoelitiana/h98QR/)

Comment: Also if they are on the home page how do i keep the 'home' link red so they know they are on the home page. For example if they go to the about us page the about us link would stay red

Comment: you can use the :active pseudo : `a:active{color:red}`

Comment: im using mvc so i dont think this will work at my menu is in the shared file

Answer (score 3):

Use `float:left`

http://htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/float/